# How to add 2 numbers in lc3 to get a sum of 4 digits?

Tags: lc3

So far i have made a code that add 2 numbers but they are single digits.

```html
.orig x3000

lea r0, string1
puts
getc
out
add r1, r0, 0

ld r0, minus48
add r1, r1, r0


lea r0, string1  ;input one
puts


LOOP
getc
out
add r2, r0, 0
ld r0, minus48
add r2, r2, r0

add r3, r1, r2
out


OUTSIDE

lea r0, string2  ;input two
puts

ld r0, plus48
add r0, r3, r0
out

HALT
plus48 .FILL 48
minus48 .FILL -48

string1 .stringz "\nPlease enter a number: "
string2 .stringz "\nSum is: "
.end
```

and this works fine however I've been trying to make the number input store more then 1 digit and this is what I've done:

```html
.orig x3000

lea r0, string1  ;input one
puts

LOOP
getc
out
add r1, r0, 0
brz OUTSIDE

ld r0, minus48
add r1, r1, r0
out 
brnzp LOOP 

lea r0, string1  
puts


getc
out
add r2, r0, 0
ld r0, minus48
add r2, r2, r0

add r3, r1, r2
out
OUTSIDE


lea r0, string2  ;input two
puts

ld r0, plus48
add r0, r3, r0
out

HALT
plus48 .FILL 48
minus48 .FILL -48

string1 .stringz "\nPlease enter a number: "
string2 .stringz "\nSum is: "
.end
```

I have tried to use a loop so I can input more then single digits and the sum can calculate up to 9999. But my loop outputs weird characters but it doesn't run like I want it, LC3 is pretty confusing like it took me forever to get the addition of single digits, so help will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't look over all of your code in detail but I'm a little confused about this first loop.

```
LOOP
getc
out
add r1, r0, 0
brz OUTSIDE
```

You're taking the ASCII char and adding 0 to check if our ASCII char is null, but you can't get a null char from the user.

```
ld r0, minus48
add r1, r1, r0
out 
brnzp LOOP
```

These next few lines will also need to be modified. Basically when these 9 lines are run you are taking a char from the keyboard converting that ASCII value to an integer, then adding that int to its ASCII value. That's why you're getting a never ending loop of random char.

I would recommend having several variables for each base 10 value.

Example:

```
; Stored values
NUM1_1    .FILL x0000    ; stores the last number entered by the user
NUM1_10   .FILL x0000    ; stores the 10's value
NUM1_100  .FILL x0000    ; stores the 100's value
NUM1_1000 .FILL x0000    ; stores the 1,000's
```

So if you where given the number 5,382 by the user you would store 5 into NUM1_1000, 3 into NUM1_100, ect... and then add digit of the two numbers separately.

Or it might be easier to have a look up table that helps you add the base 10 values as the user types them in.

Example:

```
LookUp10       .FILL  #0
               .FILL  #10
               .FILL  #20
               .FILL  #30
               .FILL  #40
               .FILL  #50
               .FILL  #60
               .FILL  #70
               .FILL  #80
               .FILL  #90


LookUp100      .FILL  #0
               .FILL  #100
               .FILL  #200
               .FILL  #300
               .FILL  #400
               .FILL  #500
               .FILL  #600
               .FILL  #700
               .FILL  #800
               .FILL  #900
```

Then you can just use the number given to you by the user as an index for the value in the array you want.

Comment: Thank you. Also where exactly do I put in the modifications? I actually do not know how to use the loop effectively... does my code need a loop at all for a user to input more than one digit?

Comment: I think a loop would be a good way to get user input, because you never know if the user only wants to add a 3 digit number and a 2 digit number together. You can keep looping for the user input until they press the ENTER key. Also, if my first comment helped, I would appreciate it if you marked it as answered.

Comment: The usual algorithm for reading multi-digit numbers is `total = 10*total + new_digit`.  LC3 should be able to multiply by 10 with a few instructions, e.g. as `reg*8 + reg*2` with shifts, or `(reg*4 + reg) * 2` using just `add` instructions to double something or add two things.  That's probably easier than lookup tables.

Comment: [Algorithm to convert integer between bases using LC-3 Assembly Language](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16379886) has multi-digit base-10 input using that `t*10 + digit` algorithm.  Just using 4x `add` instructions for the multiply by 10, saving `reg*2` while computing `reg*8`.