# lc3 assembly, How to add two user input numbers and output it?

Tags: assembly, lc3

After storing two numbers, how do you add them together and display the answer??

This is what I have so far, I just need to output the answer at the end. Any help would be appreciated:

```
.orig x3000

lea r0, LN1
puts

lea r2, NO1

LOOP1

getc

str r0, r2, 0       
add r2, r2, 1       
add r1, r0, -10     
brz OUT1

out         

brnzp LOOP1 

OUT1

lea r0, LN2

puts

lea r2, NO2

LOOP2

getc

str r0, r2, 0       
add r2, r2, 1       
add r1, r0, -10     
brz OUT2

out         

brnzp LOOP2 

OUT2

lea r0, LN3
puts


halt

NO1 .blkw 15

NO2 .blkw 15

LN3 .stringz "\nSum: "

LN1 .stringz "\nEnter first number: "

LN2 .stringz "\nEnter second number: "

.end
```

Comment: How large do the numbers from the user have to be? Also it looks like you're storing the ASCII value of the numbers the user types in, you'll probably want to convert those to integers.

Comment: numbers between 0 and 999

Comment: I would recommend starting with the information in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30115783/how-to-add-2-numbers-in-lc3-to-get-a-sum-of-4-digits and then reposting your code if you have any more issues.